# pass model to view using viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewbag

i want to send two model in my view
and in other page maybe and need more

controller

```
ViewBag.Users = db.Users.ToList();
```

and in View

```
@using Documentation.Models

@{
    var Users = (Documentation.Models.User)ViewBag.Users;
}

<table>
@foreach (var item in Users) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item.username)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

but i get no answer , i know my code is not right

i got this error

```
 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Documentation.Models.User' because 'Documentation.Models.User' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Comment: Looks like there are two major problems with your code. Like @Peri mentioned, you're not casting to a container of Users. Also I think `@Html.DisplayFor(item.username)` will throw an error since you're not using an expression like `item => item.username` so I suggest you use `@Html.Display(item.username)` instead =]

Comment: i think problem is in `@foreach (var item in Users)` or in `var Users = (Documentation.Models.User)ViewBag.Users;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should cast viewbag.model to List of User. Not to User.

```
@{
    var Users = (List<User>)ViewBag.Users;
}
```